# Block popups from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, popup, windows-services

There is a `service` installed under local user account. Under some conditions, it can generate `popups`. Is it possible, using another application or service, to prevent that service from generating these Popups, programmatically?

There are `popup blockers` for `browsers`. Maybe something on those lines? Of course, the mechanism of popup generation might differ, but I'd like to avoid any popups from the service.

Comment: The easiest way is to uninstall that service.

Comment: Sadly, not an option. It does something useful.

Comment: If you know process of that service, you can just close all it's windows (you can put this command into a timer and set interval to 1).

Comment: By "local user account", I take it's not setup to run as Local System?

Comment: @toadflakz Yes, it doesn't run under SYSTEM, rather a user account.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the service's ability to interact with the desktop when running under a local user account (as opposed to using Local System account) by disabling interactive services through a registry entry. This does however disable interactive services for the entire OS but is the only way to achieve this without running the service under a Local System account and disabling the "Interact with Desktop" option under the Service Configuration.

All the details can be found in this article: [HowToGeek: Lesson 8: Understanding and Managing Windows Services](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson8/)

Comment: Is it possible for the service to be logged in as a particular user, say X (this is fine), but somehow remove X's ability to display any popups on the desktop, and can the service be run under X, while another user Y is using the actual system? (long shot maybe). Also, which registry option should be disabled to remove the interactive permission, the one on the page is probably for the system services, and anyway it is disabled.

Comment: No, as far as I understand the options, you can only disable interaction globally or if the service starts under the Local System account. Just remember the disabled value is 1, not 0.

Comment: Yes, it's set as 1, and I suppose it's for all the Services in LocalSystem account. Can't see how to turn them off for a LocalUser service.

Answer (score 0):

If the popups are holding up the action, simply hiding them won't do much good. Look at tools like [Buzof](http://www.basta.com/Buzof) that can automatically dismiss the popups -- provided you run it as a service in Session 0.

Comment: They don't hold up anything, but are annoying, the messages are wrong (service obtained from a 3rd party ), and I'd rather the messages didn't show up in the first place. They popup at a very quick interval, so their appearance and subsequent disappearance can cause a bad visual effect.

Comment: How do the popups cause a bad visual effect? Aren't they coming up in the isolated Session 0?

Comment: Nope. They come up on the desktop, in session1. i.e., like a normal popup. It's not like the "Service wants your attention" popup, which comes up in restrictive session 0.

Comment: That is highly unusual! What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: 8.1. I think it is using the WTSSendMessage send messages to the desktop. I had imagined it is using another program, interacting with it through some IPC, but no such process, either in task bar, or in the registries, in RUN, or RunOnce, is there. Only the service.